# how to get correct count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Folks,
I am trying to do something here but it is not working out. Basically I want to list open items but if some quantity has already been shipped out. I want to deduct it from open items.

Open column = Ordered quantity - billed quantity but if some part of that original order has already been billed then that needs to be deducted too.

### My query

```
SELECT 
so.so_create_on AS 'Sales_Order_Created_On',
so.sales_order AS 'Sales_Order',
li.so_item 'Sales_Order_Item',
so.site_id_name_1 'Site_ID_Name_1',
li.order_quantity AS 'Order_Quantity',
li.so_net_price AS 'Sales_Order_Net_Price',
(li.order_quantity * li.so_net_price) AS 'Sales_Order Net Value',
bi.bill_item AS 'Billed_Item',
bi.bill_qty AS 'Billed_Quantity',
bi.bill_doc_date AS 'Billed_Document_Date',
(bi.bill_qty * li.so_net_price) AS 'Billed Net Value' 
FROM sap_sales_order so 
LEFT JOIN sap_so_line_item li ON so.sales_order = li.sales_order 
LEFT JOIN sap_billing bi ON so.sales_order = bi.sales_order AND (li.so_item = bi.bill_item or bi.bill_item = 0)
```

### Query result

```
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Sales_Order_Created_On | Sales_Order | Sales_Order_Item | Site_ID_Name_1 | Order_Quantity | Sales_Order_Net_Price | Sales_Order Net Value | Billed_Item | Billed_Quantity | Billed_Document_Date | Billed Net Value |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
| 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             845 | 2015-11-23           |           845.00 |
| 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               20 | DEF            |           8800 |                  1.00 |               8800.00 | 20          |            8800 | 2015-11-23           |          8800.00 |
| 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |            1050 | 2015-12-14           |          1050.00 |
| 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             500 | 2015-12-21           |           500.00 |
| 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             105 | 2015-12-21           |           105.00 |
| 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            1000 | 2016-07-18           |          1000.00 |
| 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            3775 | 2016-07-29           |          3775.00 |
| 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            2500 | 2016-07-29           |          2500.00 |
| 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            2225 | 2016-10-19           |          2225.00 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               10 | ABC            |              1 |              50000.00 |              50000.00 | 10          |               1 | 2017-02-08           |         50000.00 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               20 | ABC            |              1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | 20          |               1 | 2017-02-08           |        145000.00 |
| 2016-07-28             | 111831121   |               10 | GHI            |             20 |                  0.75 |                 15.00 | 10          |              20 | 2016-07-29           |            15.00 |
| 2016-07-28             | 0111831121  |               20 | GHI            |             50 |                  0.75 |                 37.50 | 20          |              50 | 2016-07-29           |            37.50 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               10 | ABC            |              1 |              50000.00 |              50000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               20 | ABC            |              1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               30 | ABC            |             15 |               2200.00 |              33000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               40 | ABC            |          25000 |                  1.00 |              25000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               10 | DEF            |           1000 |                  1.00 |               1000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               20 | DEF            |           1450 |                  1.00 |               1450.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               30 | DEF            |            145 |                  1.00 |                145.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               40 | DEF            |            880 |                  1.00 |                880.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

### What I want (Compare Open column values)

```
+------+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Open | Sales_Order_Created_On | Sales_Order | Sales_Order_Item | Site_ID_Name_1 | Order_Quantity | Sales_Order_Net_Price | Sales_Order Net Value | Billed_Item | Billed_Quantity | Billed_Document_Date | Billed Net Value |
+------+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
| 1655 | 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             845 | 2015-11-23           |           845.00 |
|    0 | 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               20 | DEF            |           8800 |                  1.00 |               8800.00 | 20          |            8800 | 2015-11-23           |          8800.00 |
| 1450 | 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |            1050 | 2015-12-14           |          1050.00 |
|  950 | 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             500 | 2015-12-21           |           500.00 |
|  845 | 2015-09-23             | 1209549436  |               10 | DEF            |           2500 |                  1.00 |               2500.00 | 10          |             105 | 2015-12-21           |           105.00 |
| 8500 | 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            1000 | 2016-07-18           |          1000.00 |
| 4725 | 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            3775 | 2016-07-29           |          3775.00 |
| 2225 | 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            2500 | 2016-07-29           |          2500.00 |
|    0 | 2016-04-28             | 1230503910  |               10 | DEF            |           9500 |                  1.00 |               9500.00 | 10          |            2225 | 2016-10-19           |          2225.00 |
|    0 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               10 | ABC            |              1 |              50000.00 |              50000.00 | 10          |               1 | 2017-02-08           |         50000.00 |
|    0 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               20 | ABC            |              1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | 20          |               1 | 2017-02-08           |        145000.00 |
|    0 | 2016-07-28             | 111831121   |               10 | GHI            |             20 |                  0.75 |                 15.00 | 10          |              20 | 2016-07-29           |            15.00 |
|    0 | 2016-07-28             | 0111831121  |               20 | GHI            |             50 |                  0.75 |                 37.50 | 20          |              50 | 2016-07-29           |            37.50 |
|    1 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               10 | ABC            |              1 |              50000.00 |              50000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
|    1 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               20 | ABC            |              1 |             145000.00 |             145000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
|   15 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               30 | ABC            |             15 |               2200.00 |              33000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
|25000 | 2017-02-03             | 1270633456  |               40 | ABC            |          25000 |                  1.00 |              25000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 1000 | 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               10 | DEF            |           1000 |                  1.00 |               1000.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
| 1450 | 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               20 | DEF            |           1450 |                  1.00 |               1450.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
|  145 | 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               30 | DEF            |            145 |                  1.00 |                145.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
|  880 | 2017-02-28             | 1275536210  |               40 | DEF            |            880 |                  1.00 |                880.00 | 0           |               0 | NULL                 |             0.00 |
+------+------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

### SQL Structure

```
--
-- Table structure for table `sap_billing`
--

CREATE TABLE `sap_billing` (
  `bill_item` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `bill_qty` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_doc_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_doc` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `bill_net_value` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_order` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `import_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sap_billing`
--

INSERT INTO `sap_billing` (`bill_item`, `bill_qty`, `bill_doc_date`, `bill_doc`, `bill_net_value`, `sales_order`, `import_date`) VALUES
('10', 845, '2015-11-23', '3206790137', '845.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('20', 8800, '2015-11-23', '3206790137', '8800.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 1050, '2015-12-14', '3209056079', '1050.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 500, '2015-12-21', '3209763880', '500.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 105, '2015-12-21', '3209763885', '105.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 1000, '2016-07-18', '3230230297', '1000.00', '1230503910', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 3775, '2016-07-29', '3231648901', '3775.00', '1230503910', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 2500, '2016-07-29', '3231648902', '2500.00', '1230503910', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 2225, '2016-10-19', '3240098774', '2225.00', '1230503910', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 1, '2017-02-08', '3250923886', '50000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
('20', 1, '2017-02-08', '3250923886', '145000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
('10', 20, '2016-07-29', '5021718928', '15.00', '111831121', '2017-03-13'),
('20', 50, '2016-07-29', '5021718928', '37.50', '0111831121', '2017-03-13'),
('0', 0, NULL, 'NA', '0.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
('0', 0, NULL, 'NA', '0.00', '1275536210', '2017-03-13');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `sap_sales_order`
--

CREATE TABLE `sap_sales_order` (
  `sales_order` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `order_reason` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_create_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sold_to_party` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_po` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id_name_1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sap_sales_order`
--

INSERT INTO `sap_sales_order` (`sales_order`, `order_reason`, `so_create_on`, `sold_to_party`, `customer_po`, `site_id_name_1`, `import_date`) VALUES
('0111831121', NULL, '2016-07-28', 'A1', NULL, 'GHI', '2017-03-13'),
('111831121', NULL, '2016-07-28', 'A1', NULL, 'GHI', '2017-03-13'),
('1209549436', NULL, '2015-09-23', '45342', 'PPQQRR', 'DEF', '2017-03-13'),
('1230503910', NULL, '2016-04-28', '45342', 'OMI1212', 'DEF', '2017-03-13'),
('1270633456', NULL, '2017-02-03', 'AV', '123456', 'ABC', '2017-03-13'),
('1275536210', NULL, '2017-02-28', '45342', '1A', 'DEF', '2017-03-13');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `sap_so_line_item`
--

CREATE TABLE `sap_so_line_item` (
  `so_item` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `material` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_quantity` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_net_price` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `so_net_value` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_order` char(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `import_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sap_so_line_item`
--

INSERT INTO `sap_so_line_item` (`so_item`, `material`, `description`, `order_quantity`, `so_net_price`, `so_net_value`, `sales_order`, `import_date`) VALUES
(10, 'M1', 'K1', 20, '0.75', '15.00', '111831121', '2017-03-13'),
(10, 'M4', 'K4', 2500, '1.00', '2500.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
(10, 'M4', 'K4', 9500, '1.00', '9500.00', '1230503910', '2017-03-13'),
(10, 'M3', 'K3', 1, '50000.00', '50000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
(10, 'M4', 'K4', 1000, '1.00', '1000.00', '1275536210', '2017-03-13'),
(20, 'M1', 'K1', 50, '0.75', '37.50', '0111831121', '2017-03-13'),
(20, 'M2', 'K2', 8800, '1.00', '8800.00', '1209549436', '2017-03-13'),
(20, 'M5', 'K5', 1, '145000.00', '145000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
(20, 'M4', 'K4', 1450, '1.00', '1450.00', '1275536210', '2017-03-13'),
(30, 'M6', 'K6', 15, '2200.00', '33000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
(30, 'M4', 'K4', 145, '1.00', '145.00', '1275536210', '2017-03-13'),
(40, 'M7', 'K7', 25000, '1.00', '25000.00', '1270633456', '2017-03-13'),
(40, 'M4', 'K4', 880, '1.00', '880.00', '1275536210', '2017-03-13');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can be more than one shipped order?

Comment: I mean, for a single order more than one shipped order.

Comment: I see open number is different -- why is it different?

Comment: @Hogan The first 4 rows are the same sales_order with a total amount (order_quantity) of 9500. Each row subtracts from the total amount via the bill_qty. Row 5 is a new order.

Comment: @Ethilium -- you have described the first table.  Now there is a difference in the second table.  Why is the second table different.  This is nomad's question how to make it different.  I don't know why it is different.  To answer this question I have to know why it is different.

Comment: I would suggest to add the column "open" to the table and update it each time you insert a new order that will make the data more readable and easy to track, especially when the data gets bigger.

Comment: @Hogan that is his dilemma. The first table is merely subtracting within each row. The second table is using the 9500 once and subtracting bill_qty each time and leaving the remainder as open. AKA 9500 - 1000 (8500), 8500 - 2225 (6275), 6275 - 3775 (2500), 2500 - 2500 (0). Row 5 pays itself off in one row.

Comment: do you need a cumulative sum?

Comment: @McNets I have updated the original question. I had to break the object further and now have three tables. Table structure and sample data is updated.

Comment: *"...but if some part of that original order has already been billed then that needs to be deducted too."* - This part is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a cumulative sum solution:

Check it here: http://rextester.com/SEZS4911

```
select if (@last_order <> sales_order, @acm_order := order_quantity - bill_qty, @acm_order := @acm_order - bill_qty) as Open,
       sales_order,
       so_create_on,
       order_quantity,
       bill_item,
       bill_qty,
       bill_doc,
       bill_doc_date,
       @last_order := sales_order
from
     (select @last_order := 0, @acm_order := 0) x,
     (SELECT sa.sales_order,
               sa.so_create_on,
               sa.order_quantity,
               sh.bill_item, 
               sh.bill_qty,
               sh.bill_doc, 
               sh.bill_doc_date
        FROM sales_order sa
        LEFT JOIN shipped_order sh ON sa.sales_order = sh.sales_order
        order by sa.sales_order, sh.bill_doc_date) y
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your quest gives the intended result.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I had to break the object further and more data. I tried tweaking the query you provided but it kept on failing. Can you have a quick look at it. I have updated the question with new table structure + sample data. This time we have three tables.

Comment: @mcnets would you be able to write it in a single statement rather than two statements using the updates I made to the original question.