# Referencing the post again

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I updated my question to seek help. Please beautiful minds of stackoverflow, have a look at it and help me out. Thanks.

[how to get correct count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658830/how-to-get-correct-count)

Comment: Hi Koby. The didn't ask the same question, I just referenced it again.

Comment: That's not something you do on SO.

Comment: So what do you suggest to get more visibility and seek assistance?

Comment: Once you posted a question, you cannot post it again. If your question lacks attention, you can set a bounty, but since you only have 11 reputation, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question being asked. It's simply referencing an existing question.

Comment: So in other words, I cannot ask a question.